# Set superclass delegate from subclass setDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, delegates

I have a superclass A that has a `BaseModalViewControllerDelegate` protocol and a retain property for the `id<BaseModalViewControllerDelegate> delegate`.
I also have class B, subclass of A, that has a `ModalLoginDelegate` protocol and a retain property for the `id<ModalLoginDelegate> delegate`

Now, I set as setter method for B class delegate this method:

```
-(void)setDelegate: (id<ModalLoginDelegate>)delegate
{
    _delegate = delegate;
    [super setDelegate: (id<BaseModalViewControllerDelegate>)delegate;
}
```

So, there is the RootViewController that implements both protocol, but it inits only B class and it set itself as delegate only for B class because it doesn't know that B class is a subclass of A.

Do you think that this is a correct way to set RootVC as delegate for both protocol? Thanks

**ADDING**

Setting the protocol of B class as inherited from A class:

```
@protocol ModalLoginDelegate <BaseModalDelegate>
    // delegate method of subclass
@end
```

Now, my RootVC has not to set itself as delegate of BaseModalViewController. But now, when in my B class I want to call the delegate method of the superclass I'm doing this

```
if (self.loginDelegate)
{
    [self.loginDelegate baseModalViewController: self willDismiss: YES];
}
```

I think that this is not a very clean way, so I created a public method in the superclass `-(void)pressedCloseButton;` that it will do this

```
-(void)pressedCloseButton
{
    if (self.delegate)
    {
        [self.delegate baseModalViewController: self willDismiss: YES];
    }
}
```

And in the subclass:

```
-(IBAction)closeBtnPressed: (id)sender
{
    [super pressedCloseButton];
}
```

Do you think is right?

Comment: If both classes have a property `delegate` then there is only a single `_delegate` iVar, so the call to `super` is unnecessary.  Your A class should fire it's delegate methods, although you should guard them to ensure that the delegate implements the appropriate protocol

Comment: It's correct, but, without casting the delegate param, Xcode return me a warning about a different expecting id. Should I ignore it?

Comment: A better design is to implement a separate delegate property for your subclass, say `loginDelegate`.  It isn't very good OO design to change the type of a property in a subclass. Most OO languages won't even allow it.  This also ensures that the class that is using your classes is "aware" that there are two separate delegate protocols involved

Comment: Alternatively, you could make the delegate on Class B conform to two protocols if you want it to always conform to Class A's delegate as well.

e.g. `@property(retain) id<ModalLoginDelegate, BaseModalViewControllerDelegate> delegate;`

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok, I think I will do it, but how can I avoid that RootVC set itself only as `delegate` and not also as `loginDelegate` ?

Comment: `RootVC` will need to set itself as both delegates if it needs to implement both protocols.  You can't expect the class not to know which delegate protocols it needs to implement.  If RootVC thinks it is only dealing with the base class then it won't set `loginDelegate` and won't implement the methods in that protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better design is to implement a separate delegate property for your subclass, say `loginDelegate`. It isn't very good OO design to change the type of a property in a subclass. Most OO languages won't even allow it.

This also ensures that the consuming class is "aware" that there are two separate delegate protocols involved.

`RootVC` will need to set itself as both delegates if it needs to implement both protocols. You can't expect the class not to know which delegate protocols it needs to implement. If `RootVC` thinks it is only dealing with the base class then it won't set loginDelegate and won't implement the methods in that protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I don't disagree with Paulw11's answer here at all, but it interesting to note that Apple themselves do this.
example.  UIScrollView has a delegate property

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <UIScrollViewDelegate> delegate;
```

and a subclass, UITableView, has a delegate property

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <UITableViewDelegate> delegate;
```

When we declare a protocol in ObjC we usually have that protocol extend the < NSObject > protocol.

```
@protocol BaseModalViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)doSomething;
-(NSString *)titleForThing;
@end
```

Now this protocol above has not only the methods prototyped here but also those in the < NSObject > protocol. Its is very much like this protocol is a 'subclass' of the other protocol, inherits all its stuff too.

If you did this with your second protocol

```
  @protocol ModalLoginDelegate <BaseModalViewControllerDelegate>
        -(void)doAnotherThing;
        -(NSString *)titleForTheOtherThing;
    @end
```

then what you've done here would be absolutely in line with what Apple have done with UITableView and UIScrollView, because a pointer of type id<  ModalLoginDelegate > is always also an object of type  id<  BaseModalViewControllerDelegate > , just as a UIButton* will always be able to be passed in as a UIView*  ...

But without doing this there is a fundamental problem in your

```
 -(void)setDelegate:(id<ModalLoginDelegate>)delegate
```

method there, because you are assuming this object complies with the BaseModalViewControllerDelegate protocol when the only thing you know for sure is that it complies with the ModalLoginDelegate protocol.  Some inherited method may call on self.delegate with a BaseModalViewControllerDelegate method which self.delegate does not respond to..
I hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi jeff, I tried with your solution and now my RootVC hasn't to setting itself as delegate of the `BaseModalViewController`, but, as @Paulw11 said, I think is better if I set RootVC as BaseModalVC delegate. It implements the protocol, so it knows about this class, so why should I hide delegate property to its?

Comment: And now, I don't know, but the `ModalLoginViewController` that it do an operation like this: `-(IBAction)closeBtnPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (self.loginDelegate && [self.loginDelegate respondsToSelector: @selector(baseModalViewController:willDismiss:)])
    {
        [self.loginDelegate baseModalViewController: self willDismiss: YES];
    }
}`
I don't think is a clean way. Maybe I have to set a public method in the superclass and call it from subclass. Then the superclass calls its delegate...

Comment: Oh mate I'm not really suggesting you do this (extend protocol 1 with protocol 2) unless it really makes sense in terms of your design.  Just do as  Paul said, but call the second delegate something else, perhaps self.loginDelegate   I just thought it interesting and applicable to your question in some cases (e.g. UIScrollView, UITableView )